# MacOS-Drag String onto NSStatusItem

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I am trying to detect when a string is getting dragged onto the NSStatusItem. Here is the implementation of my code in AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
         if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("StatusBarButtonImage"))
          button.action = #selector(menubarAction(_:))
            button.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])
            button.window?.registerForDraggedTypes([.string ])
            button.window?.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

And here is my NSWindow delegate calls:

```
extension AppDelegate:NSWindowDelegate{
    
    func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation{
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true )

        return .copy
    }
    
    func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool{
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true )

        return true
    }
}
```

However these delegates do not get called when a string is dragged onto the NSStatusItem. I know that drag has been detected as:

```
applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification)
```

gets called. Any suggestions why my delegate is not getting called.

Thanks

Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`draggingEntered` and `performDragOperation` are methods of protocol `NSDraggingDestination`. Swift doesn't call a protocol method if the class doesn't adopt the protocol. `AppDelegate` must adopt `NSDraggingDestination`.

```
extension AppDelegate: NSWindowDelegate {
}

extension AppDelegate: NSDraggingDestination {
    
    func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation{
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true )

        return .copy
    }
    
    func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool{
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true )

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: As I can not create a custom window for the button, and NSWindow does allow you to set NSDraggingDestination as a delegate, how can I make the window associated with the button to respond to my implementation of the Drag calls

Comment: thanks it worked. I can now see why it does work, but for me, it is not very intuitive.